# Partitioning SQL query by arbitrary number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a SQL table with periodic measurements.  I'd like to be able to return some summary method (say SUM) over the value column, for an arbitrary number of rows at a time.  So if I had

```
id  |  reading
1      10
5      14
7      10
11     12
13     18
14     16
```

I could sum over 2 rows at a time, getting (24, 22, 34), or I could sum 3 rows at a time and get (34, 46), if that makes sense.  Note that the ID might not be contiguous -- I just want to operate by row count, in sort order.

In the real world, the identifier is a timestamp, but I figure that (maybe after applying a `unix_timestamp()` call) anything that works for the simple case above should be applicable.  If it matters, I'm trying to gracefully scale the number of results returned for a plot query -- maybe there's a smarter way to do this?  I'd like the solution to be general, and not impose a particular storage mechanism/schema on the data.

Comment: in Oracle that would be a window function with a user defined aggregate function.

Comment: Not sure I follow - you group by columns, not rows. If you want an arbitrary number of rows that would be a parameter in the `WHERE` (or `HAVING`) clause surely?

Comment: I want an arbitrary number of rows in the *result* set, but I want all the data to "make it in" to the result, if that makes sense.  I might be showing 1000 hours of data (recorded hourly) but only need 50 points to make a useful graph, so I'd like to aggregate every 20 rows into one result.

Comment: Randy, ntile looks like just about exactly what I want (partition the complete result into N partitions, act on each partition) but I don't know how to support it in MySQL.  Still reading about that....

Comment: @Coderer I get you now. Perhaps change the wording to something like '_aggregate_ data using arbitrary scale'?

Comment: Widor: updated.  Hopefully that removes the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may resequense query result and then group it

```
SET @seq = 0;

SELECT SUM(data), ts FROM (
    SELECT @seq := @seq + 1 AS seq, data, ts FROM table ORDER BY ts LIMIT 50
) AS tmp GROUP BY floor(tmp.seq / 3);
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood this.  This is going to group into partitions of 3 rows, because the first 3 rows (seq = 0, 1, 2) will have a value of 0 in the group by clause, then 1 for seq = 3, 4, 5, etc.  I didn't get it at first, but it's realy clever!